# Google Analytics Measurement Protocol Not in View

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've integrated Measurement Protocol to add pageviews.  I also have 2 views of my Google Profile for the property.  The Measurement Protocol pageviews **are** showing up in my default view (which I call Raw Data), but the pageview **are not** in the alternative view which has "Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders" enabled.  The only difference is the alternative view has "Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders" enabled.  Would that exclude Measurement Protocol pageviews?  How to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED - You need to set the ua parameter to override the default agent, which is recognized as a bot/spider and omitted from the view due to the "Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders" being enabled.